# How to get Key and Value from JSON object in Javascript(Postman)

Tags: javascript, json, postman, key-value

I have a JSON object like this, I wanna access the list array elements with key and value in postman.

```
{
    "data": {
        "total": 1,
        "list": [
            {
                "id": 53,
                "name": "Sonu",
                "mobileNo": "6543213456",
                "address": "Greeny Pathway",
                "city": "NewYork",
                "mode": "Weekly",
                "duration": "15",
                "qty": null

            }
        ]
    },
    "success": true,
    "message": ""
}
```

How to separate it as Key and Value in Javascript like,

```
Key:   id,name,mobileNo,address,city,..
Value: 53,Sonu,6543213456,Greeny Pathway,NewYork,....
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). If you have an object or array, then you have an object or array, full stop. JSON format is a *method of representing an object in a string*, like `const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}'`. If there are no strings, serialization, or deserialization involved, then JSON is not involved either.

Comment: Would you be able to also share what you've tried so far and what result you got from it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally this works for me!(In Postman Script)

```
var resdata = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(resdata);

key = Object.keys(resdata.data.list[0]);
console.log(key);

value =Object.values(resdata.data.list[0]);
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove comma from line :  `"qty": null,` otherwise it will cause error in json parsing.

```js
var resultJSON = `{
    "data": {
        "total": 1,
        "list": [
            {
                "id": 53,
                "name": "Sonu",
                "mobileNo": "6543213456",
                "address": "Greeny Pathway",
                "city": "NewYork",
                "mode": "Weekly",
                "duration": "15",
                "qty": null

            }
        ]
    },
    "success": true,
    "message": ""
}`;


var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);

var myList = result.data.list[0];

$.each(myList, function(k, v) {
    //display the key and value pair
    alert(k + ' is ' + v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below codes:

```
const keys = Object.keys(jsonObject);
const values = Object.values(jsonObject);
```

But your JSON object is deep, you should flatten it and then use `keys` and `values` of `Object` to make them separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can get using key and value separately in a array.

```js
var a = {
    "data": {
        "total": 1,
        "list": [
            {
                "id": 53,
                "name": "Sonu",
                "mobileNo": "6543213456",
                "address": "Greeny Pathway",
                "city": "NewYork",
                "mode": "Weekly",
                "duration": "15",
                "qty": null,

            }
        ]
    },
    "success": true,
    "message": ""
}

var keyval = Object.keys(a.data.list[0])
console.log(keyval)
var values = Object.values(a.data.list[0])
console.log(values)
```

Comment: I cant able to understand your question can you explain more?

Comment: The above format is my Json obj, I want to retrieve keys and values separately from the list[], I used JSON.parse to parse it, nxt step?

Comment: you can use "var a = JSON.parse(responseBody);"

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects are key value pair you cannot get the keys and values in object form as you desire but you can get both in form of arrays from this code

```
var key = []
var values = []
list.map(function(l){  keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(l); 
keys.map(function(key) {values.push(l[key]);})})
```